# How to make visual studio highlight keywords

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

Here is a picture of how it looks now:
[image: How it use to look]

I had to reinstall visual studio and when I started programming I noticed something was off.
For example, GameObject and Vector3 used to be the same color as MouseLook. Update and OnDrawGizmos used to be some other color too.
Does anybody know how to revert that? It is so annoying like this. But it's not the only problem.

When I type Vector3. it ussualy lists me its components, for example Vector3.forward or left, right, zero, one and so on. It doesn't do that now.

Please help me with this :/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Intellisense must not be working properly.

Make sure you have the [Visual Studio Tools for Unity](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/unity-tools/) setup.

Comment: so intellisense handles this? Ah thanks, I think I know what to do now.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to "fix" this is to get into unity, go under edit, preferences, external tools and under external script editor choose Visual Studio